# Printing an Exception in Debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, printing

My issue lies within the catch statement.  The try executes, but the Exception is seemingly never caught and will not print to the Debugger.  The results state that an Exception was never handled and a FindElementException was thrown, although that is exactly what I'm trying to catch.

```
private void verify(HtmlControl obj, int timeout)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++)
        {
            obj.Wait.ForExists();
            //break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exceptions.FindElementException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could Not Verify Object" + obj + "Exists.  Exception: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all very much for your help and input with the subject, but this morning I was able to find documentation via a MSDN Blog about the subject.  For future reference, this is a common problem with the x64 version of Windows and, unfortunately, there isn't much anyone can do to work around the issue.  Following is the text from the Microsoft Blog, pictures and figures removed (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/05/12/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application.aspx):

> Why can’t the debugger catch/break on my unhandled exception on x64 versions of Windows?
>
> The reason this happens on x64 versions of Windows is a design
>   decision by the Windows operating system; x64 versions of Windows do
>   not allow user mode exceptions to propagate post a kernel transition
>   on the call stack.  What happens is when an exception is thrown in an
>   application, it travels backward on the call stack until it either
>   reaches an exception handler or the application’s “Main()” method.  If
>   the exception reaches the application’s “Main()” method without being
>   handled, the debugger recognizes that the exception went unhandled and
>   breaks the application where the exception occurred.  As shown below,
>   the Form_Load method causes a kernel transition, so when an exception
>   thrown in a Form_Load method reaches the kernel frame on the
>   callstack, the operating system catches the exception.  Since the
>   exception is caught before it reaches the “Main()” method, from the
>   debugger’s perspective the exception was caught—the debugger is unable
>   to determine that the exception was caught by the operating system ,
>   not the user code.
>
> How can I tell if this is my problem?
>
> This problem can manifest itself in different ways depending on the
>   type of exception.  Both Windows Forms, and WPF applications have
>   exception handling code in the underlying framework that will catch
>   certain types of exceptions (e.g. NullReferenceException), so in some
>   cases your application will crash with an unhandled exception, in
>   other cases the form will load and appear, however the Form_Load
>   method (and all subsequent calls) will not have correctly run to
>   completion.  There will however be a message in the “Output” window
>   that “A first Chance exception of type ‘’ occurred in
>   ”.
>
> Workaround
>
> Unfortunately there isn’t a lot the debugger can do in this case since
>   the operating system catches the exception (explained above).  The
>   workaround in Visual Studio is to enable “First Chance” exceptions for
>   the exception types that are being thrown in the Form_Load method.  To
>   to this:
>
> Navigate to the “Debug” menu, and select “Exceptions” Check the
>   “Thrown” box for the “Common Language Runtime Exceptions” row.  (Note:
>   You can expand the Exceptions using the “+” sign and only check the
>   "Thrown” box for the desired exceptions"

Thank you all again for your time and input!

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest turning on breaking on all exceptions in Visual Studio, so that you can inspect the exception when it occurs. You can do this by going to `Debug (menu) > Exceptions...` and select all the checkboxes. Maybe the FindElementException has a different namespace than what you are expecting? I suspect you are not catching the type of exception that you are intending to.

Comment: I also tried using a general "Exception ex" in the catch, as well, but that had the same effect.  I'm a little confused as to why it never reaches the catch block to begin with.

Comment: If `Exception ex` doesn't catch it, then it is not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a generic catch in there, and put a breakpoint in that catch. This way, when it catches, you can inspect that error message and find out what the exception really is that it's throwing. Once you find that out, you can change your code to expect THAT exception, instead of the one you have.

Step 1) change your code to this:

```
private void verify(HtmlControl obj, int timeout)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++)
        {
            obj.Wait.ForExists();
            //break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exceptions.FindElementException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could Not Verify Object" + obj + "Exists.  Exception: " + ex);
    }
    catch {} // PUT THE BREAKPOINT HERE
}
```

Step 2) Run and find out the exception being thrown. Comment if you don't know how to do this, and I will explain (assuming you're using VisualStudio or another compiler that uses breakpoints)

Step 3) Update your code to this:

```
private void verify(HtmlControl obj, int timeout)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++)
        {
            obj.Wait.ForExists();
            //break;
        }
    }
    catch (INSERTNEWEXCEPTIONTYPEHERE ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could Not Verify Object" + obj + "Exists.  Exception: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried to execute the code as stated, but the funniest part about running the code through the Debugger is that it doesn't seem to reach the catch block after the try.  Every time it runs, the exception gets thrown earlier in the code and terminates prior to the break point.

Comment: I am only trying to test this method to verify that it works with two iterations of the method, and I know it works for objects that ARE present, but the ones that are not do not get caught as an exception.

Comment: That's weird.. the program shouldn't terminate if the error is in the try-catch block. Are you sure it even gets to the try-catch block? try putting other bits of code in try-catch blocks. Or better yet, if your debugger has the capability of "stepping in" to the code, put a breakpoint in the last line you know for SURE works, and then "step in" from there